# gnu emacs on windows - how to maximize without mouse?

Tags: windows, emacs

GNU Emacs on windows:

I have discovered that my usual way of maximizing a window without the mouse does not work.

I usually (in other apps/editors this works, gvim for instance) would press ALT+SPACE to bring up the top-left corner menu, and then press X (the hot key for maximize).

To restore a window would be ALT+SPACE and then the R key.

For some reason this doesn't work in gnu emacs.... is there anything i can do to stop reaching for my mouse constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[I found one answer among many on EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc14):

```
(w32-send-sys-command #xf030)
```

The `#xf030` is a system command code to maximize the window.

Comment: That would be a more logical way oh doing it. Good find. ( though <kbd>C-z</kbd> should also work to mimizie )